# Wrap cells of tabular in macro

Tags: tables, memoir, tabularx

I would like to use the column specification syntax of memoir's tabular environment to automatically wrap cells of a table in a macro.
Is that possible? I tried the following

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newcommand\bracketit[1]{[#1]}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l>{\bracketit\bgroup}c<{\egroup}}
    1 & A \\
    2 & B \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which fails with

```
! Missing } inserted
```

I had hoped it would be equivalent to

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newcommand\bracketit[1]{[#1]}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
    1 & \bracketit{A} \\
    2 & \bracketit{B} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

but without the typing. Of course, with the simple `\bracketit`, there is no need for a macro, I could insert the brackets directly. However, the macro that I want to apply is not that simple and out of my hands (`mhchem.sty`'s `\ce`). Is what I try to do possible at all?

Comment: Take a look at the [collcell package](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/collcell/collcell.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with the [`collcell`](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/collcell/collcell.pdf) package:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{collcell}
\newcommand\bracketit[1]{[#1]}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{l>{\collectcell\bracketit}c<{\endcollectcell}}
    1 & A \\
    2 & B \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```